# Realtek audio jack insertion status registry setting for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have requirement to poll windows registry settings to detect if audio jack is inserted in to my computer. My computer has Realtek audio.

With Realtek audio manager (application), it would detect when I insert headphone in to computer but is there any way I can access some registry settings to detect whether something is inserted in to audio jack or not?

I believe there should be a way to detect as Realtek audio manager has that capability.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would depend on what you do. Did you have a look at registry changes when you plugin a device? Did you look for an SDK or similar that you could use to interface with the driver to do that detection?

Comment: Just because it is detectable via software does not mean that the setting is stored in the registry. More likely is that you need to look at whatever SDK is available for Realtek products and see if there is an API to detect the headphone state.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996159/detect-headphones-on-a-laptop-in-windows